# Lista dados de duas tabela no tableView

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

Com que faço para lista dados de duas tabela no tableView?

Banco de dados(Exemplo) Sqlite:

```
tb_venda
  tb_produto
  tb_valor
  tb_cliente_id (Id do cliente "tb_cliente")

tb_cliente
  tb_cliente_id (id primary key)
  tb_nome  
  tb_estado
```

Com `QSqlRelationalTableModel` consigo trazer apenas o nome do cliente. 
Preciso também do estado.

```
relacao = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this); 
relacao->setTable("tb_venda");
relacao->setRelation(2, QSqlRelation("tb_cliente", "tb_cliente_id", "tb_nome"));
relacao->select();
ui->tableView->setModel(relacao);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido:
O `QSqlRelationTableModel` traz apenas uma coluna. 
Para solucionar o problema, tive que usar o `QSqlQueryModel` com `LEFT JOIN`.